# How to repressurize a vacuum chamber really fast?

Tags: spacesuits, vacuum

There was an accident during a suit test in a vacuum chamber on December 14, 1966. The suit lost pressure and

> The chamber – which would normally take 30 minutes to repressurized –
> was blasted back to atmospheric pressure in 87 seconds.

[Source](http://www.spacesafetymagazine.com/aerospace-engineering/space-suit-design/early-spacesuit-vacuum-test-wrong/)

How did they blast the chamber back to atmospheric pressure in only 87 seconds? Was there an emergency hatch with explosive bolts ready for a case of need?

Comment: I don't see why you would need explosive bolts, an inward-opening hatch would seem perfectly sufficient.

Comment: hard to imagine why it would take 30 minutes to repressurize since there is an infinite supply of air at pressure just outside.

Comment: @PeterGreen There is a lot of force acting on an inward-opening hatch to a vacuum chamber. To open the hatch interlocks under full load may require much force without a special design and lubrication of the locks.

Comment: @Woody For a fast repressurisation you need not only an infinite supply of air, you also need a large cross-sectional area of the air inlet. Air speed within the inlet could not be faster than sound.

Comment: The chamber doesn't seem to be too big, maybe 10m³. Repressurization within 87s can be done through a 5cm² inlet.

Comment: I'd guess that they did something like loosening a c-clamp on a flange connecting a pump (or some other item) to a port on the chamber, then tilted it opening a gap on one side, or just opened a valve that wasn't connected to anything at the moment. (This is how I used to it for non-critical/non-UVH/not-particularly-clean vacuum chambers) As @asdfex points out a small-sized opening is all you need, so no particularly large forces involved. The "30 minutes" may have been standard to allow  clean venting from dry compressed air from a tank or through a filter, or to avoid plumbing differentials.

Comment: There's some math for calculating flow rates through holes between atmosphere and vacuum in [this answer to *How could the 2018-08-30 Soyuz MS-09 / ISS leak be so slow?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30553/12102)

Comment: normal repressurization might have taken more factors into account - such as strain on the chamber itself or operating procedures - but in case of an emergency there should always be a method of "just opening a large valve"

Comment: @asdfex Using this https://www.tlv.com/global/TI/calculator/air-flow-rate-through-orifice.html calculator with 1 bar primary pressure, 0 bar secondary pressure, 25.2 mm diameter of the orifice with 20 °C I get 9.1 m³ per minute. But the increasing chamber pressure during repressurisation was not considered, therefore we get a shorter time than real.